# Git commit metadata without a writable file system?

Tags: git

I need the time stamp that a given remote has attached to a given commit (the value that would be used for `--shallow-since`) and need to avoid doing a `clone`. In theory it should be possible to get that without having a local repository. If nothing else, run the same requests as a clone but never write anything to disk, however some of [the docs I've found](https://git-scm.com/docs/http-protocol#_the_negotiation_algorithm) seem to suggest that part of the normal fetch workflow includes sorting yet-to-be-fetched commits based on "commit time", which suggest what I'm need can be done. But everything I've found says that isn't supported and "just clone the repo".

But that don't work in my case because I don't have a file system I can use for that clone. (And even if I did, even a `--depth=1` clone could result in arbitrarily large amounts of data being transferred, which I can't allow.)

I've been digging thought the docs trying to figure out how the protocols work to see if I can abuse it to give me what I need, but so far haven't been able to figure out how it's supposed to work.

Comment: There's no need to sort by time, and in fact, doing so would be suspect at best because the time stamps (both of them) *in* each commit are unreliable because they are generated by unreliable clocks on unreliable computers, and/or forced by malicious users to fool professors, etc. You also can't *see* the time stamps in the commits you don't have yet, and the protocol negotiation exists so that you can limit the transfer to those commits that you don't yet have.

Comment: Well, the git docs are the ones talking about sorting, not me. What I need is the value to stuff here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/repo/git.html#git_repository-shallow_since Also, I suspect that commit time are "accurate enough" in practice. Globally syncing clocks to within a few seconds is more or less a solved problem.

Comment: Your link (to git-scm.com) goes to a section that's actually talking about the sending process, not the receiving process; you'd be the receiver, not the sender. So its claim about sorting is not relevant in the first place. The sender can feel free to sort by any criteria they like, since they're the sender, but there's no need to sort at all: the sender can just run in topological order, or whatever order is convenient.

Comment: Meanwhile, the bazel shallow-since documentation just wants a string it can pass to `git fetch`. If you're planning to use the bazel API, be aware that they just invoke Git!

Comment: I think that doc is talking about the *client*, the receiver of the data, doing sorting. Sure everyone can sort by whatever they want, but the fact it's saying sort by commit time suggest that it's possible to do that. Really I don't care about the sorting, just that for that to be possible requires first doing something else that I do care about. -- As for bazel, sure it will use git, but that's only relevant under the assumption that it and my project run in equivalent contexts, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Again, the receiver literally *can't* sort the incoming commits by dates, because it does not have the date stamps: those are in the commits that they don't have yet. Take a look at some actual commits (use `git cat-file -p HEAD` for instance): you'll see the two dates. Now think about why a receiver is receiving a commit object....

Comment: So what is the official git documentation I was quoting from saying the client should do? Is that documentation in error? -- If the wire protocol has the ability to send something other than complete commits files, then what `cat-file` shows doesn't actually say much.

Comment: The `git-scm.com` documentation you're quoting isn't official Git documentation: it's part of the Pro Git 2 book instead. (Other files on `git-scm.com` are actual Git documentation though. I know it's all a bit confusing and jumbled: the way to understand this is that `git-scm.com` is the Pro Git web site, and they autogenerate the reference documentation from Git, but they do their own thing for the Pro Git book pages.) The wire protocol is all about selecting and sending objects; they're sent as either individual objects or pack files; and until you have them, well...

Comment: Anyway, the trick here is to figure out how to do the wrapping with http/https (if you're dead set on that) or with ssh (if that's an option), and then figure out the rest of the wire protocol, from the Git source. The high level description at `git-scm.com` is mostly correct as far as I know, but may have small glitches. I've never tried to implement any of this myself. Look also in the Git source at the `Documentation/technical/` directory files. They're also not guaranteed to be correct but they're likely to have fewer bugs than anything but the source.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way integrated with the standard `git` binary to run git commands on the remote, or to have that kind of info without writing the objects first somewhere on your filesystem.

Some possible workarounds :

- If your target repo is hosted on a service that provides an API (Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, Azure Devops ...), you can use the API.
- If you have some way to access the hosting machine, you can run your git command remotely, e.g :

  ```
  ssh hostingserver 'cd repo && git log -1 <commit>'
  ```

  Note that you can do that with any system that has a clone of your repo (your CI server, ...).

Some more intricate workarounds :

- Some git implementations (other than the standard `git` binary) allow you to store the repo structure completely in RAM (`go-git` and `JGit` do that, for example). You will need to write some code in target language, and have the resulting exe at hand from your system.
- Perhaps you can find a way to mount a temporary filesystem on the target system ? a ramfs, or a network drive ?
- Read the [Transfer Protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) section of the docs and see if you can get through using only installed tools. If you manage to download the commit object you are interested in, the [Object storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#_object_storage) section will tell you how to make sense out of it.

Comment: The only thing I can assume is a remote URL and network access to it. I can't assume any given server implementation. It's safe to assume I *don't* have shell access. And it's not safe to assume a CI server exists and is accessible to me. And even a ramfs requires filesystem access at least to mount it. -- Your last bullet point is more or less what I spent yesterday trying to figure out, but I can't seem to get anything beyond the `ls-refs` step to work.